# LINQ - Complex Sorting

Tags: c#, linq

I am querying a table of Order elements with LINQ (C#). Each Order has the following fields:

```
- ID
- OpenDate
- PriorityID
- StatusID
- Description
```

The StatusID field maps to a Status table. The Status table is structured as:

```
- ID
- Name
```

I need to get all of the Order objects sorted by their Priority and Status.
I can successfully get the Order objects sorted by Priority. I'm doing this via the
following:

```
List<Order> orders = new List<Order>();
using (DBDataContext context = new DBDataContext())
{
  orders = (from o in context.Orders
            orderby (o.PriorityID.HasValue ? o.PriorityID : Int32.MaxValue)  ascending
            select o).ToList();
}
```

But my problem is factoring in the Status.

Once the order objects have been sorted by priority, I need to sort the Order objects
in the following order of Status: Cancelled, Open, In-Route, and Delivered. Significantly,
The IDs of these Status values are firmly set in a random, non-helpful order. I cannot alter them. As you can tell, I can't sort the status by alphbetical name either. In addition, I can't add any fields to my database. Can anyone tell me how I can solve this problem in LINQ?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you also taking a top (Take) here? I'm wondering if it needs to be done at the DB, or if it can sort in the .NET code...

Comment: Yes, how many items are needing to be sorted? If you can do it client-side, then an IComparer or Comparison delegate `List.OrderBy(x, y=>...)` would be plenty.

Comment: can you add a calculated field to your Order class at the front-end? Then you could sort by that field. Something like: "select new {SortField = Calculate the sort index here}".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have solution to this by implement IComparer and use Linq to order it. Since your Status is not in numeric nor alphabet order.

```
public class CustomComparer : IComparer<Status>
{
     public int Compare(Status statusA, Status statusB)
     {
       if (statusA.StatusName == "Cancelled" && statusB.StatusName == "Cancelled")
       {
          return 0; // equals
       } 
       else if (statusA.StatusName == "Cancelled" && statusB.StatusName != "Cancelled")
       {
          return 1; // A > B
       }
       ....
     }
}
```

then

```
orders.OrderBy(x => x.Status, new CustomComparer())
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would put a switch-case statement instead of ifs, as the sequence order is very specific and may change or new items added later.

Comment: I like this approach. However, I now get a "Unsupported overload used for query operator 'ThenBy'" error when I run the following line:                     var results = context.Orders.OrderBy(p => p.PriorityID ?? Int32.MaxValue).ThenBy(s => s.StatusID, new CustomComparer()).ToList();

Comment: Probably because that can't be expressed as SQL. You an cache the orders in an array and then you should be able to apply the sorting (might not be pratically possible though for performance reasons)

Answer (score 1):

As long as the list of statuses are going to be consistent, you could create a string such as "COID", and compare two statuses based on "COID".indexOf(firstletterofstatus). Maybe not the best software practice, but it would work.

Answer (score -1):

If it's not going to a long list (i.e. it will reasonably fit in memory), you could sort client side with a mapping between statuses and relative orders:

```
int StatusOrder(Status status) 
{
    switch(status.Id)
    {
       case 1: return 5;
       case 2: return 1;
       case 4: return 3;
       //etc
    }
}

List<Order> orders; //no need to create a list here
using (DBDataContext context = new DBDataContext())
{
    orders = (from o in context.Orders
        orderby (o.PriorityID.HasValue ? o.PriorityID : Int32.MaxValue)  ascending,
                SorderOrder(o.Status)
        select o).ToList();
}
```

Comment: -1: Will give runtime exception, because it can't translate `StatusOrder` to SQL.